# Library to convert JSON to JSON schema

Tags: json, schema

I'm looking for a library that would convert a JSON to a schema.

jsonschema.net is an online tool, but what I want is a library I could use in my code. Similarly, to convert CSV and TSV to JSON schema as well.

Comment: FYI: Requests for library recommendations are strictly off-topic on StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to contribute to [Schemify](https://github.com/sachi-d/Schemify) . Demo on [Demo page](https://sachi-d.github.io/myApps/Schemify/).